# WPF DataGrid Totals Row

Tags: wpf

I have a simple Datagrid and I wanted to display a Totals row at the bottom of the Datagrid. I know there are many ways of doing this but I chose to have a second DataGrid at the bottom to hold Column Totals. The Top (main) DataGrid would be bound to some Data Table whilst the bottom (Total DataGrid) with one row would be bound to Data Table Column totals that I would generate using some formula.

The magic of what I am trying to do is that whenever I rearrange the column positions on Top the bottom Columns should also be rearranged accordingly. Similarly if I alter Column width on the Top DataGrid the bottom column width should also change accordingly.

1. Regulating the width at the bottom appears easy enough in that I have used XAML binding as follows using Column 1 s an example:  `Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column1}, Path=ActualWidth}"`. The reason why I chose the `x:Reference` is that (I am told) there is no easy way of referring to `DataGrid` Column names other than using the x reference (Assuming this is true). I have noticed that the width binding above is underlined to show that binding is not being recognized although at run time it works.
2. Synchronising the Column positions of the Bottom `DataGrid` to those of the Top `DataGrid`, however, could only be done in code behind as doing it like this: **`DisplayIndex="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column1}, Path=Actual DisplayIndex }"`** does not work and freezes the application.

I have Two Questions:

1. How can I change the XAML above to make the binding faster?
2. How Can I use XAML binding to handle any changes in Column Index (position) without using the code behind?

Here is the XAML and the c# code behind

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid  >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="273*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="TopDataGrid" ColumnDisplayIndexChanged="TopDataGrid_ColumnDisplayIndex">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column1" Header="Column 1" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column2" Header="Column 2" Width="3*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column3" Header="Column 3" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column4" Header="Column 4" Width="*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="BottomDataGrid" Grid.Row="1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn  x:Name="TotalColumn1" Header="Total Column 1" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column1}, Path=ActualWidth}"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TotalColumn2" Header="Total Column 2" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column2}, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TotalColumn3" Header="Total Column 3" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column3}, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TotalColumn4" Header="Total Column 4" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column4}, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and here is the code behind that regulates any changes in column index (position)

```
 private void TopDataGrid_ColumnDisplayIndex(object sender, DataGridColumnEventArgs e)
        {

            TotalColumn1.DisplayIndex = Column1.DisplayIndex;
            TotalColumn2.DisplayIndex = Column2.DisplayIndex;
            TotalColumn3.DisplayIndex = Column3.DisplayIndex;
            TotalColumn4.DisplayIndex = Column4.DisplayIndex;

        }
```

Like I have said, I am sure there are other (and even better) ways of doing what I am trying to achieve. But please help me with this one before you suggest other ways.

**Surely out of 7 billion of us there must be someone who can solve this. We do not need UFOs to solve it!!!!!**

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to the `DisplayIndex` property programmatically once the columns have been initialized:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(TotalColumn1, DataGridColumn.DisplayIndexProperty, new Binding("DisplayIndex") { Source = Column1 });
    };
}
```

Comment: Nop. I tried it and it fails. Remember even with  Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column1}, Path=ActualWidth}", although it works at run time, the binding is extremely slow especially with more data. DisplayIndex="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column1}, Path=DisplayIndex}" does not work. This is why I am forced to use the code behind

Comment: It works just fine for me. Please provide a MCVE to prove your point: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Copy the XAML above and try to change one line say:  

<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TotalColumn1" Header="Total Column 1" Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column1}, Path=ActualWidth}" DisplayIndex="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column1}, Path=ActualDisplayIndex}" />

It hangs up and I get the following error message after stopping the debug: 

The DisplayIndex for the DataGridColumn with Header 'Total Column 1' is out of range.  DisplayIndex must be greater than or equal to 0 and less than Columns.Count.

Comment: Hello mm8. Yes it works. But before I mark it as answered, just address one issue for me and that is the fact that Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Column1}, Path=ActualWidth}" is extremely slow binding especially with lots of data.

Comment: This is not reproducible based on the information you have supplied. Please ask a new question if you have another issue and make sure that you include a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve